# Rigidity of Lie Algebra

Tags: deformation-theory

I Know the theorem: if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a lie algebra and  $H^{2}(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g})=0$ (second space of cohomology in Chevaley-Eilenberg complex) then $\mathfrak{g}$ is rigid ... but I am interested in to Know when  The reciprocal of this theorem is true?.